# Spring boot test : run tasks before and after all tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, embedded-database

I want to run a task (say spin up a db) before all spring boot tests and shutdown the db after all the tests are run.

I don't want to use @Before or @BeforeClass as this causes the tasks to run before and after each tests or test classes.

We want to run them before all tests/test classes and after all tests/test classes

We are using the @SpringBootTest annotation on our test classes.
_

Comment: I do not khnow what you will do with this bd and what kind of db you use ? try plz to give more details !

Comment: We want to know how to run a task before all tests and after all tests. Spinning a db is just an example of task.

Comment: you do a superClass where you defind your init method annotated with `@BeforeAll` and an other method annoted with `@AfterAll` , then all your test class extends that super class ?

Comment: But we have a number of tests. This will run the task before and after each test class, but we just want to run it once. We are thinking of spinning a db (https://github.com/wix/wix-embedded-mysql) and we want to spin it and close it down just once.

Answer (score 1):

To execute something before all tests are started, you could manipulate the start of the spring-boot-context by defining a class in the test-package and annotate it with `@Configuration`. There you could do custom logik like populating your `DataSourceInitializer` on different DataSources or other stuff.

For the after all tests you could implement a ShutdownHook, also implemented in your test package, so that when the spring-boot-context is shutdown it will execute your hook.